# Change default "Save to account" text in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

I'm using the stripe gateway to process payments. There is a piece of text that comes from woocommerce "Save to account" which isn't very descriptive for my purposes. This text is located in [`WC_Payment_Gateway` `save_payment_method_checkbox()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html#445-458)

Ideally, it'd be something like "**Save my credit card details for future purchases (optional)"**.

Support have suggested I install a translation plugin just to change these three words, which seems to me like a huge overkill.

Any ideas on how to best change this?

Comment: Please try WooCommerce hooks or filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that it's on checkout page… If it is the case, try the following that should do the trick:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'change_save_to_account_text', 100, 3 );
function change_save_to_account_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( $text === 'Save to account' && $domain == 'woocommerce' && is_checkout() )
    {
        $translated_text =  __( 'Save my credit card details for future purchases (optional)', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> **If it's not on checkout page**, replace `is_checkout()` by the correct [conditional  tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)…

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of `hooks` and `filters` available in WooCommerce WordPress. You override layout and functionality in WordPress by using these `hooks` and `filters`

For Example:

```
  <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received">
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?>
</p>
```

[WooCommerce hooks and filters list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)